# How to assign a angular directive to a div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a grid where I add divs dynamically when user clicks a button. I should assign a directive to a div before adding it to a grid. Assume that $scope.selectedDirective holds the directive name as a string.

suppose $scope.selectedDirective='directiveA', I want this div to be added to the grid:

```
<div class="content-block" directiveA></div>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="content-block" {{selectedDirective}}></div>
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: there should be an attrib helper, or just add the attrib on with the dom...

Comment: Create the template with the directive dynamically. Use $compile for compiling the created template. Append the compiled element in the place you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe I'm using is

```
app.directive('someDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        priority: 10000,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var oldDirective;
            attrs.$observe('directive', function (directive) {
                if (directive && element.attr(directive) === undefined) {
                    oldDirective && element.attr(oldDirective, undefined);
                    oldDirective = directive;
                    element.attr(directive, '');
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                }
            });      

        }
    };
});
```

The usage is

```
<div class="content-block" some-directive="{{selectedDirective}}"></div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @estus. :)